# How to align Material Design Lite cards to right hand side

Tags: html, css, css-float, material-design, material-design-lite

I'm trying to build a simple page which have cards using material design lite components but one problem stucks the whole layout of the page. How to align the 
**mdl card** to right hand side of the screen ? I have tried by **float:right;** in css then the card is only shifting towards right in that same col not to the screen. Help me to shift it

```html
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
    <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
        <div class="mdl-card__title">
            <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Welcome</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
            <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                Get Started
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-card__menu">
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                <i class="material-icons">share</i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an mdl-layout-spacer to the left of the card should help. mdl-layout-spacer takes up as much space as it can.

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
  <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
    <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <div class="mdl-card__title">
        <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Welcome</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
        <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
          Get Started
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__menu">
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
          <i class="material-icons">share</i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bro the card doesn't get responsive after I add spacer to card. Is there any alternative that makes card responsive ?

Comment: You can try setting the card's width and height as a percentage in your css so that it's responsive:

.mdl-card {
  height: 10%;
}

Answer (score 5):

Try this class `mdl-typography--text-right`, in this way, the contents in that cell will have an alignment of `right`:

```
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-typography--text-right">
    <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
        <div class="mdl-card__title">
            <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Welcome</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
            <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                Get Started
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-card__menu">
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                <i class="material-icons">share</i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Vice versa: `mdl-typography--text-center` and `mdl-typography--text-left` also work.

Answer (score -2):

To align text try use: `text-align:right;`

Comment: Dude I want to shift whole card to right side of window